# Visual example of PostGIS ST_Extent

Tags: postgis, extents

[`ST_Envelope`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) and [`ST_OrientedEnvelope`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html) have visual examples in the docs:

[image: ST_Envelope example] [image: ST_OrientedEnvelope example]

How would a meaningful example for [`ST_Extent`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) look like?

Comment: Just like ST_Envelope.

Comment: Except type is a box2d if not transformed back to geometry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two viz in QGIS to show result (only using points as it was simpler)

```sql
-- no group version
With dataset AS (
  SELECT column1 AS id, column2 AS geom FROM (
  VALUES (1, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3 5)'), 4326)),
       (2, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 6)'), 4326)),
       (3, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 7)'), 4326))
  ) As foo
)
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(geom), 4326) FROM dataset;
```

[image: ST_Extent without grouping]

```sql
-- group version
With dataset AS (
  SELECT column1 AS id, column2 AS mygroup, column3 AS geom FROM (
  VALUES (1, 7, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3 5)'), 4326)),
       (2, 7, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(4 6)'), 4326)),
       (3, 4, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 7)'), 4326)),
       (4, 7, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(8 3)'), 4326)),
       (5, 4, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10 4)'), 4326)),
       (6, 4, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 13)'), 4326))
  ) As foo
)
SELECT mygroup, ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(geom), 4326) AS geom FROM dataset GROUP BY mygroup;
```

[image: ST_Extent with grouping]